IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup: SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183
I am trying to deploy a dotnet web app to Windows Server 2022 via Azure Pipelines using IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0 task.
  - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
    inputs:
      IISDeploymentType: 'IISWebsite'
      ActionIISWebsite: 'CreateOrUpdateWebsite'
      WebsiteName: '${{ parameters.websiteName }}'
      WebsitePhysicalPath: '${{ parameters.physicalPath }}'
      WebsitePhysicalPathAuth: 'WebsiteUserPassThrough'
      CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: true
      AppPoolNameForWebsite: '${{ parameters.websitePoolName }}'
      DotNetVersionForWebsite: 'No Managed Code'
      PipeLineModeForWebsite: 'Integrated'
      AppPoolIdentityForWebsite: 'ApplicationPoolIdentity'
      AddBinding: true
      Bindings: |
          {
              bindings:[
                  {
                      "protocol":"https",
                      "ipAddress":"All Unassigned",
                      "hostname":"${{ parameters.hostname }}",
                      "port":"443",
                      "sslThumbprint":"${{ parameters.sslThumbprint }}",
                      "sniFlag":true
                  }
              ]
          }
      ServerNameIndication: true
      ConfigureAuthenticationForWebsite : true
      AnonymousAuthenticationForWebsite: false
      WindowsAuthenticationForWebsite: true

The first time I deployed worked just fine, but the next deployment gave this error:
SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 183
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

I found a work around by deleting the ssl certs with a previous task like this:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Remove ssl certs
    continueOnError: true
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        netsh http delete sslcert hostnameport=${{ parameters.hostname}}:443

Is there any better solutions to allow multiple deployment wihtout removing ssl certs everytime.

You should add your Workaround as an Answer as it works to solve the problem.

The workaround you are using is a good choice. I noticed it's bug, which was fixed in February this year, but there are still people having the same issue. I will try to contact the product team and confirm if it's possible to reopen that ticket. At the same time, you can create a new ticket here to report your current issue.

Thanks! I found also another issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/issues/1008  related to the task I am using IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0

Thanks for sharing. I have tried to confirm with the product team if it's possible to reopen the old ticket. Besides, you can create a new ticket on Developer Community since the old one was closed, so that you can communicate with the support engineer directly and he can help you report this issue to product team.
